# PGL(2,F) acting on a tree

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, trees, geometric-group-theory

I'm currently studying representation theory of groups related with trees.
One of the sources I'm reading talks about "$PGL(2,\mathcal{F})$ thought of as a group of automorhpisms of its canonical tree".

By the context I could infer the following: $PGL(2,\mathcal{F})$ is supposed to be a proper closed subgroup of the automorphism group of this "canonical" tree.

I'd like to know what this tree is and what if the (whole) automorphism group of this tree is known / what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: What source are you using, and what page does this quote occur on?

Comment: And what kind of mathematical object is $\mathcal{F}$? Presumably some particular kind of ring?

Comment: @SantanaAfton it appers in A. Figa-Talamanca and C. Nebbia, Harmonic Analysis and Representation Theory for Groups Acting on Homogeneous Trees, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1991. on page 98

Comment: @LeeMosher That I do not know, the author does not specify that. For me it would suffice if there was a suitable object that would meet the description. I thought it might be some field, maybe finite, but who knows

Comment: I am sure that ${\mathcal P}$ is supposed to be a field with a discrete valuation (or, more generally, a nonacrhimedean valued field, but in this case one has to be more careful with the notion a tree used here). A standard reference for all this is J-P. Serre "Trees".

Answer (score 1):

One can make a matrix group $GL(2,\mathcal F)$ out of any commutative ring, by taking $2 \times 2$ matrices possessing a unique inverse. One can mod out by diagonal matrices to give the quotient group $PGL(2,\mathcal F)$. However, there is not always a tree associated to this construction, although there is usually some other kind of geometric object.

For instance, when $\mathcal F = \mathbb R$ then the group $PGL(2,\mathbb R)$ acts on the [upper half plane with the hyperbolic metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_half-plane).

On the other hand, when $\mathcal F = \mathbb Z$ then $PGL(2,\mathbb Z)$ acts very naturally on a tree.

And when $\mathcal F$ is the field of p-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_p$ then $PGL(2,\mathbb Q_p)$ acts very naturally on a tree.

I do believe there is a general theory explaining when a choice of the ring $\mathcal F$ leads to an action of $PGL(2,\mathcal F)$ on a tree, and it might seem the book you are reading would say that theory is, if one looked in the right place. But I'm not familiar with that book.

The trees can be explained in the various different cases, and a real answer to your question would contains some kind of explanation, but I'll stop with this for now.

Comment: Thank you very much! If this is not too time consuming: Is (for example in the case $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{Z}$ the tree that $PGL(2,\mathcal{F})$ acts upon a tree whose automorphism group is indeed larger than "just" $PGL(2,\mathcal{F})$. A good reference for the cases where the group acts naturally on a tree might also help me. In any case, thank you!

Comment: The trees that arise in these constructions tend to be constant valence trees, in which case the full automorphism group is an uncountable group. So yeah, the automorphism group is usually hugely larger thabn "just" $PGL(2,\mathcal F)$.

Comment: I'll try to add a couple of examples to my answer in the next day or two, if no-one else picks this up.

Comment: The basic "general theory" is based on the notion of discrete valuation, I think.